# Android Studio Layout Preview Builder had Render Problem because of findViewTreeLifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, preview

I'm trying to implement a custom view with ViewModel and LiveData.
If so, I need to get findViewTrrLifecycleOwner to observe the LiveData.
In the runtime, it worked properly.
But in Layout Preview, it's occured Render Problem because lifecycleOwner is null.
Is it not good way to refer liveData in Custom View? Or is there another way to get lifecycleOwner?

```kotlin
class CustomView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null) :
    FrameLayout(context, attributeSet) {
 init {
        doOnAttach {
            initClickListener()
            initObserver()
        }
    }

    private fun initObserver() {
        val lifecycleOwner = findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()!! // the problem point
        viewModel.liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner) {
            arrowView.x = it
        }
}
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.customview.CustomView.initObserver(CustomView.kt:120)
    at com.customview.CustomView.access$initObserver(CustomView.kt:19)
    at com.customview$special$$inlined$doOnAttach$1.onViewAttachedToWindow(View.kt:413)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:58)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:366)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:717)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:873)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:192)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you manage to solve this problem?